# Python process objects within JSON array based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, json, object, nested

I need to process 10k JSON files in a folder called "All_Files", having names as Result_1.json, Result_2.json and so on, and having the following structure:

```
{
    "kind": "string",
    "url": {
        "type": "application/json",
        "template": "string"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "string",
            "link": "https://www.somewhere.com/..."            
        },
        {
            "kind": "string",
            "link": "https://www.anywhere.com/..."            
        },
        {
            "kind": "string",
            "link": "https://www.nowhere.com/..."            
        },
        ...
        
        }
    ]
}
```

It is to be noted that a single JSON file may or may not contain an **"items"** array. Also, if the **"items"** array is present, then it can contain one or more objects as given in the example above. The **"link"** key contains full URLs. If the **"items"** array is present, then I need to access the **"link"** key and search for a specific substring that begins with "https://www.nowhere.com". There could be additional string after "https://www.nowhere.com" in a **"link"** key, but I need to match only the first part as described. If the first part matches, we need to save the name of the .JSON file having this particular key value in a text file called **"Found.txt"**, one unquoted filename on each line in the file.

Please help me in writing a Python script that does this.

Comment: Please share, What did you tried to do this, what did you found while researching about your problem?

Comment: This is part of a large research problem that I am part of. We are analysing responses from various search engines on some given criteria.

Comment: I had already gave you answer as idea to solve your problems, but if you had provided some code that you had tried then I may had gave you some code also, but you didn't present anything  that you had tried so, do on your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the list of files and opening them you can do but this will only work if you have jsons files only in that directory.

```
import os 
print(os.listdir("/path/to/All_Files"))
```

And now you have name of all files in that directory the you can open those files by using either `json` or just `with`.

Loop through all the files, read files and change Data type of content of the file to `str` by using doing `content=str(content)` **content is the data inside file that we have read already and saved in content.** and now you got data in every iterations. Add this code in loop:

```
pattern=r"(?i)(\b(https?|http):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])"

urls=[x[0] for x in re.findall(pattern,content)]

if "https://www.nowhere.com/" in urls:
    with open("found.txt","a+") as f:
        f.write(f"Found in {<file name we got previously using os.listdir()>}")
```

We had used `re` so, don't forget to import it in your program.